# How to render Excel header full visible when title is vertically aligned and table's filtering is activ?

Tags: excel, header, vertical-alignment

All my headers in an Excel file are displayed `vertically` and the `filter is activ`.

I have defined alignment parameters of each cells like this

```
Horizontal alignment: LEFT
Vertical alignement: TOP
```

But my result is not very readable because first characters of header are combo button of filter ! See green title in following image

[image]

I can change the horizontal alignment from LEFT to RIGHT, but this is not very readable when you navigate into headers.

I can change the vertical alignement from BOTTOM to TOP (or CENTER). This work well for majority of cells but not for cells with small width !

When I edit alignement properties in Excel, I have the possibility to define a `Indent` value ... but this work only when vertical alignment is not activ !

How can I align vertical headers correctly even when filter is activ ?

Answer (score 1):

Add 8 (or more) non breaking spaces just before header's text.

To to that, press ALT+255 where 255 is typed on Keypad.

And you obtain

[image]

This is very tricky and the name of column has been changed.